# onActivityResult crash after language changed

Tags: java, android

Running into the trouble, when an Activity which was started by startActivityForResult I'm changing language in Settings - and then after returning in that activity I hit back button - MainActivity crashes, so my code is here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        retryButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        page = 0;
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            editor.remove("savedURL");
            editor.remove("isLocation");
            editor.apply();

            filterButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.filter_selected));

            adapter.getHeaderButton().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            headerLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            String filtersPrice = sp.getString("price_saved", "");
            String filtersStuff = sp.getString("finder", "");
            cityName = sp.getString("cityID", "");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersStuff)) {
                text = cityName + "<font color=#B5B5B5>, " + spanWithRoubleTypeface(filtersPrice + "\u200A\u20BD/сутки" + filtersStuff) + "</font>";
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice) && TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersStuff)) {
                headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
                textViewFilters.setText(", цена, комнаты");
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice)) {
                Log.d("FILTER", filtersStuff);
                headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
                textViewFilters.setText(filtersStuff);
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
                textViewFilters.setText(spanWithRoubleTypeface(", " + filtersPrice + "\u200A\u20BD/сутки" + filtersStuff));
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            adapter.updateLogo();

            FilterData filterData = data.getParcelableExtra("FILTER");
            String rooms = filterData.getRooms();
            String type = filterData.getType();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(type)) {
                type = "";
            }
            String price = filterData.getPrice();
            if ("&price=50\u200A000".equals(price)) {
                price = "";
            } else {
                price = "&price=" + filterData.getPrice();
            }
            Log.e("PRICE", price);
            cityID = filterData.getCity();
            cityName = filterData.getCityName();
            String lat = data.getStringExtra("lat");
            String lng = data.getStringExtra("lng");

            String filtered = data.getStringExtra("filtered");
            String findText = data.getStringExtra("textFilter");

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filtered)) {

                filtered = "";

            }

            CityDatabase cd = new CityDatabase(MainActivity.this);
            cityID = cd.getCityIdByName(cityName);
            currencyID = cd.getCurrencyIdByName(cityName);
            currencyID = "643";

            filter = "";

            String locationURL = "";
            cityList.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (data.hasExtra("location")) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lat) || TextUtils.isEmpty(lng)) {
                    locationURL = data.getStringExtra("location");
                    locationURL = locationURL.replace("null", "0.0");
                    editor.putString("isLocation", "false");
                    editor.apply();
                    emptyRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    emptyRequest.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.emptyRequest));
                    Log.e("filter3", locationURL);
                } else {
                    locationURL = data.getStringExtra("location");
                    filter = "type=" + rooms + "&sleeping_places=" + type + price
                            + filtered + locationURL;
                    Log.e("filter1", filter);
                    filter = filter.replace(" ", "");
                    url = Api.BASE_URL + "/city/" + cityID + "/flats/";
                    editor.putString("filterURL", filter);
                    editor.apply();
                    loadFromUrl();
                }
            } else {
                filter = "type=" + rooms + "&sleeping_places=" + type + price
                        + filtered;
                filter = filter.replace(" ", "");
                Log.e("filter2", filter);
                url = Api.BASE_URL + "/city/" + cityID + "/flats/";
                editor.putString("filterURL", filter);
                editor.apply();
                loadFromUrl();
            }


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            String filtersPrice = sp.getString("price_saved", "");
            String filtersStuff = sp.getString("finder", "");
            page = 0;
            adapter.getHeaderButton().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            headerLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersStuff)) {
                text = cityName + "<font color=#B5B5B5>, " + spanWithRoubleTypeface(filtersPrice + "\u200A\u20BD/сутки" + filtersStuff) + "</font>";
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice) && TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersStuff)) {
                headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
                textViewFilters.setText(", цена, комнаты");
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice)) {
                Log.d("FILTER", filtersStuff);
                headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
                textViewFilters.setText(filtersStuff);
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
                textViewFilters.setText(spanWithRoubleTypeface(", " + filtersPrice + "\u200A\u20BD/сутки" + filtersStuff));
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            adapter.updateLogo();
            cityList.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            loadFromUrl();
        }

    } 

}
```

And here is error log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.kvartirka.android_new/ru.kvartirka.android_new.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {ru.kvartirka.android_new/ru.kvartirka.android_new.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3346)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {ru.kvartirka.android_new/ru.kvartirka.android_new.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3974)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4356)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at ru.kvartirka.android_new.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:747)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6475)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3970)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4356)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The line which one 'causes an NPE is this one:
adapter.getHeaderButton().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

I tried to add `onConfigurationChanged` but that didn't help much.

I assign button like this in adapter:

```
@Override
    public OffersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (viewType == 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.logo_layout, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView, viewType);
        } else {
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.offers_singleitem, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView, viewType);
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

public View getHeaderButton() {
        return headerLogo;
}

 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
if (position > 0) {
                    roomNumbers = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.roomNumbers);
                    address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);
                    description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.conditionsTextView);
                    metro = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.metroTextView);
                    offerImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    prices = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceTV);
                    cottageImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cottageImage);
                    roomsImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.roomsImage);
                    metroImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.metroImageView);
                    noImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.noImage);
                    roomsTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.roomsTV);
                    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                } else {
                    headerLogo = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerLogo);
                    ImageView clickableView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.clickableView);
                    filterButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
                    cancelButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
                    headerTextLogo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerTextLogo);
                    textViewFilters = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFilters);
```

And my onCreate, onResume and onPause methods

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMaxScrollPosition = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.scrolled);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBar));
    }

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;

    swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);

    emptyRequest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyRequest);

    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

    cityName = sp.getString("cityID", null);

    CityDatabase cd = new CityDatabase(MainActivity.this);
    currencyID = cd.getCurrencyIdByName(cityName);
    currencyID = "643";
    cityID = cd.getCityIdByName(cityName);

    retryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retryButton);

    if ("804".equals(currencyID)) {
        currencyID = "980";
    }

    text = cityName + "<font color=#B5B5B5>, " + "цена, "
            + "комнаты" + "</font>";
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.containsKey("userID")) {
            url = Api.BASE_URL + "/city/" + cityID + "/flats/";
            setContentView(R.layout.alloffers_activity);
            userID = extras.getString("userID");
            String ownerName = extras.getString("ownerName");
            filter += "user_id=" + userID;
            Log.d("userID", userID);
            adapter = new OffersAdapter(MainActivity.this, cityList, "", currencyID, false);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
            if (toolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(ownerName);
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_shadow);
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onBackPressed();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }

        } else if (extras.containsKey("FILTER")) {

            FilterData filterData = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("FILTER");
            String rooms = filterData.getRooms();
            String type = filterData.getType();
            String price = filterData.getPrice();
            cityID = filterData.getCity();
            cityName = filterData.getCityName();
            String filtered = intent.getStringExtra("filtered");

            text = cityName + "<font color=#777777>, " + price
                    + " ₽/сутки" + "</font>";
            button.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));


            url = Api.BASE_URL + Api.CITY_URL + cityID + "/flats/";

            filter = "type=" + rooms + "&sleeping_places=" + type + "&price=" + price
                    + filtered;

            adapter = new OffersAdapter(MainActivity.this, cityList, text, currencyID, true);
        }
    } else {
        url = Api.BASE_URL + "/city/" + cityID + "/flats/";
        adapter = new OffersAdapter(MainActivity.this, cityList, text, currencyID, true);
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sp.getString("isLocation", ""))) {
        loadFromUrl();
    } else {
        emptyRequest.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.emptyRequest));
        emptyRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    String filtersPrice = sp.getString("price_saved", "");
    String filtersStuff = sp.getString("finder", "");
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersStuff)) {
        text = cityName + "<font color=#B5B5B5>, " + spanWithRoubleTypeface(filtersPrice + "\u200A\u20BD/сутки" + filtersStuff) + "</font>";
    }

    CharSequence spannedPriceHint = spanWithRoubleTypeface(text);

    headerLogo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.headerLogo);

    headerTextLogo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerTextLogo);
    textViewFilters = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewFilters);
    cancelButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    filterButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.filterButton);

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice) && TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersStuff)) {
        headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
        textViewFilters.setText(", цена, комнаты");
        filterButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.filter));
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filtersPrice)) {
        Log.d("FILTER", filtersStuff);
        headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
        textViewFilters.setText(filtersStuff);
        cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        filterButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.filter_selected));
    } else {
        headerTextLogo.setText(cityName);
        textViewFilters.setText(spanWithRoubleTypeface(", " + filtersPrice + "\u200A\u20BD/сутки" + filtersStuff));
        cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        filterButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.filter_selected));
    }

    final String finalCityName = cityName;

    filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilterActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cityID", finalCityName);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilterActivity.class);
            String[] parts = text.split("<");
            String city = parts[0];
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.remove("isLocation");
            editor.apply();
            intent.putExtra("currencyID", currencyID);
            intent.putExtra("cityID", city);
            intent.putExtra("reset", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    headerLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapFilterActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cityID", finalCityName);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_MAP);
        }
    });

    swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            cityList.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            page = 0;
            loadFromUrl();
            emptyRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            retryButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
            adapter.getHeaderButton().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            headerLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
    swipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.blueAppBar);

    ObservableRecyclerView cityListRecyclerview = (ObservableRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    cityListRecyclerview.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    cityListRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    cityListRecyclerview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    cityListRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);

    cityListRecyclerview.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (loading && !fromCache) {
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    loading = false;
                    page += 20;

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userID)) {
                        loadFromUrl();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    retryButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: the problem is not inside onActivityResult itself, when you change any configuration, e.g. language or orientation change, you activity is recreated, i.e. onCreate etc is run. For your case, you should have set the `HeadButton` somewhere in your code, which is not in onCreate

Comment: Adapter.gerHeaderButton() returns null, which is set null somewhere in onPause/onStop or onDestroy when you leave the application for the settings. Review this!

Comment: Can you try reloading your layout within the method onActivityResult? What do you get after that?

    `setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So analyze your LogCat output:

It tells you:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at ru.kvartirka.android_new.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:747)
```

That means: After you left for the settings, the headerButton was set to null for whatever reason and causes the NullPointerException on access in onActivityResult.

Usually the headerButton should be set once in onCreate or onCreateView (if you'd be using fragments).
Obviously however you create it somewhere else.
Once you leave for the settings dialog, onPause and onStop will be called. Once you return onStart and onResume.

(Freshen up your knowledge here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

So somewhere in onPause/onStop/onStart/onResume (actually in this order) you either set the adapter to null and/or create a new adapter instance, also removing your headerButton reference, or you immediately destroy your reference to it.

Please provide more information (preferrably code) on where you create and persist your reference to the headerButton.

Comment: I assign the adapter in the onCreate with the others variables, in the adapter I have the method to assign the text to button like this
public View getHeaderButton() {
        return headerLogo;
}
Also I'll add some code to my post.

Comment: please update your question above with  the affecting code. This description doesn't help so far.

Comment: The ViewHolder class is not properly posted.
Please also show the onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause and onStop code that interacts with your adapter in any way.

Comment: Added them to post to.

Comment: Could you please post the complete adapter code? It is still incomplete (position > 0..., function header missing etc. )